# Complexity of not P or EXPTIME

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

**Question 1:** Is it possible to create an algorithm for deterministic Turing machine that will run not in P neither EXPTIME?

**Question 2:**
For me it seems that the answer for my question is `it is impossible`. If my reasoning is correct, it means that any function that describes complexity will have `polynomial(x)` or `2^polynomial(x)` form.

Does my reasoning is correct?

Comment: What reasoning?

Comment: Does this comment is useful? (hint, grammar is important.)

Answer (score 2):

A function $f(n)$ is [time-constructible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function#Time-constructible_definitions) if there is a Turing machine that runs in time exactly $f(n)$, where $n$ is the input size (in bits). Kobayashi, in his paper [On proving time constructibility of functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397585900155), showed that if $f(n)$ can be computed in time $O(f(n))$ then $f(n)$ is time-constructible. In particular, functions like $n^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}$ are time-constructible, even though they lie strictly between polynomial time and exponential time.

In fact, the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) even shows that there are some decision problems which can be computed in time $O(n^{\log n})$ but not in polynomial time. This shows that there are problem not in $\mathsf{P}$ which can be computed in faster than exponential time.

Comment: Adding to this, the same hierarchy theorem lets us construct problems with optimal running time roughly $O(2^{2^{2^n}})$ (or worse), which is neither polynomial nor 2^polynomial.